# GKE Gateway GCPBackendPolicy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We have deployed an external gateway of type `gke-l7-regional-external-managed` in our GKE cluster (1.27.8-gke.1067004).  This is working fine and we have successfully added HTTPRoutes and HealthCheckPolicy for our backend application.

What we are struggling with is adding a GCPBackendPolicy which references a Cloud Armour security policy.  This is what our manifest looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: GCPBackendPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-allow-list
  namespace: app-ns
spec:
  default:
    securityPolicy: my-allow-list
  targetRef:
    group: ""
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
    namespace: app-ns
```

This appears to deploy fine - if we do a describe on the resource the status says attached:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-03-11T17:19:22Z
    Message:               
    Reason:                Attached
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Attached
```

However, if we check the load balancer backend service in the console the `Backend security policy` field is empty, and the policy does not take affect.

We are able to attach the security policy to the backend service manually via the console, so we think the policy is valid.

Note the GCPBackendPolicy is in the same namespace as the backend service.  The Gateway resource is in a different namespace.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

oh never mind, I found the answer.  Its hidden in this table of Gateway class capabilities:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities#additional-services

Cloud Armour policies are not supported for regional external gateways.  It would be helpful if this was noted in the docs for configuring Gateway policies ‌‌

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources#configure_cloud_armor